# Xamarin.Android - how to change only 1 item when the users fling

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin, I created an Image Gallery where I see only one image on the screen, but when I swipe, multiple images go from right to the left, depending on the swipe speed. Can you please tell me how to swipe only 1 image at a time, no matter how fast I swipe?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I'm looking for a solution written in C# for Xamarin, not in Java for Android Studio.